# How come Unity won't run on my IBM Thinkpad T42?

Tags: 11.04, unity

Why won't it run on my Thinkpad T42?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at this link and then edit your question adding more detail? http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: A Note to Users: Please do not add your "I have the same problem, can you help?" posts as answers to questions.  Instead, please post your questions as separate questions.

Answer (score 3):

The command `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` should print out specific information on exactly which graphics card feature is missing.

- [How do I know if my video card can run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34579/how-do-i-know-if-my-video-card-can-run-unity)

Answer (score 2):

Probably (and most likely) it is not able to run on your hardware, and you should report a bug on unity. Unity is still in the early stages of development.
Also, if you are running on open-source drivers, you may not be able to get the full experience (depending on your hardware again, but you don't say).

As an aside, this kind of question isn't likely to get a useful answer without a bit more information.

Comment: I am running a IBM Thinkpad T42. On a site, it said it was just because Unity requires specific graphic cards, but I wanted to make sure that was it. If it doesn't, I just messed up my SuSE Groupwise Server for no reason! :(

Answer (score 0):

does compiz work fine in natty for you? unity have a few more requirements that usual compiz though it might have something to do with the fact that your laptop does not come in minimal system requirements https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements

Answer (score 0):

Well I now have Ubuntu 11.10 on a Thinkpad t42 but unlike on previous versions of Ubuntu it automatically starts in 2d mode.If you are using an older version of Ubuntu you may like to try this guide.

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)

It will be slight;ly different than Unity 3d but still works very well and the difference is limited mainly to being able to change icons positioning on the bar.

As it happens the T42 although a really useful and well buit machine has a relatively old Graphics card. Mine is the ATI 7500 and this does not work with the fglrx driver.

If you interested in boosting your T42 with Linux (as it runs really well ) I would also recommend the Thinkwiki site :

[Linux on Lenovo T42](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:T42)

They have helped me as I hada Bios that needed updating and they had a really good guide to doing this with no Windows (although scarey it worked a dream!)

They also point to the problems with the ATI graphics card :

[ATI issues on Lenovo T42](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ATI_Mobility_Radeon_7500)