# How do I know if my video card can run Unity?

Tags: unity

I have an old laptop which has some 3D graphics support, how do I know if this will be enough for Unity to run?

Comment: Just so you know, even if you can't use Unity, Unity 2d is an awesome alternative with pretty much the same features. It is a little behind the Compiz version when it comes to new features updates, but I run Unity-2d on a 10+ year old laptop perfectly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This isn't a full answer but a good place to start including the link at the bottom.
http://www.inalogic.com/component/content/article/34-general/63-demystifying-unitys-graphics-hardware-requirements

So you can run

```
 /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

which should give you some detailed output about Unity's requirements and if they are met, e.g.:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 6600 GT/PCI/SSE2/3DNOW!
OpenGL version string:  2.1.2 NVIDIA 270.30

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity supported:          yes
```

(Note, this graphics card is six years old and I'm having no performance problems running Unity.)

Though as an anecdote I have tried unity-2d on an old laptop with a substandard graphics card (Dell D600) and to be honest I still like it.  I'm not saying everyone will love the switch to Unity, but I have decided to give it a go in whatever form I can and see if I grow to like it, so far I really do.

- [Hardware Requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements)
- [Wiki page with more information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DemystifyingUnityGraphicsHardwareRequirements)

Comment: ...and the link gives a 404 Not Found.

Comment: `unity_support_test` is in package “nux-tools” (at least in natty).

Answer (score 4):

- You download a live CD and test it.
- You visit [linux on laptops](http://www.linux-on-laptops.com/) and read for your model, if somebody tried and succeeded

Answer (score 2):

Well you can go to unity.ubuntu.com and check the minimum requirements for unity. If you have an intel card, the minimum is the i945 and i965. Old ATi cards provide a much better performance than their Intel counterparts, Nvidia cards can pretty much handle unity 3d pretty well. Hope this works for you

Comment: Is the Intel GMA 4500MHD compatible?

Comment: Yes it is very much compatible