# Can Unity run smoothly on an HP Mini 210-1000

Tags: unity, intel-graphics, system-requirements

I own an HP Mini 210-1000, and I am aware that it meets the system requirements for the Unity shell. My concern is that, with my previous unfortunate experience with the 10.10 UNE version of Unity, my netbook won't be able to smoothly run Unity.

My computer specs are:
CPU: 1.66GHz Intel Atom
Memory: 1GB DDR2, 667MHz
Graphics: Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 3150

I am currently using Unity 2D on Maverick via the PPA, but I'm not very productive with window managers apart from Compiz. I'm also aware that the Compiz Unity won't be backported to Maverick, which is understandable, but still a shame.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That mini should run Unity just fine. (Much better than in 10.10). See here for more information:

- [How do I know if my video card can run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34579/how-do-i-know-if-my-video-card-can-run-unity)