# Will my Intel video graphics work with compiz?

Tags: unity, compiz, graphics, intel-graphics

I have an old Intel Graphics card (from around 2002-2003). Compiz used to work fine until 9.10 but after 9.10, using Compiz via the terminal gives the following output and reverts to 2d interface:

```
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : default
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
compiz (opengl) - Fatal: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap is missing
compiz (opengl) - Fatal: Software rendering detected
compiz (bailer) - Info: Ensuring a shell for your session
```

Metacity compositing works fine but I really want to try out Unity in Natty. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at this question and then edit your question adding more detail?   http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I know if my video card can run Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34579/how-do-i-know-if-my-video-card-can-run-unity)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your graphics card doesn't support the level of OpenGL composting required by Unity.

In such a situation you can't use Compiz Unity (also known as Unity 3D) but you can get an experience nearly similar to that of Unity Compiz by installing [unity-2d](http://packages.ubuntu.com/unity-2d)

```
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
```

I have been using Unity 2D for quite some time and its very very similar to Unity 3D.

Comment: An addition to Bilal's answer: Even if it does work, it will be very choppy. I speak from personal experience.