# "you do not have the hardware required to run Unity" on VMware

Tags: 11.04, unity, vmware

On Ubuntu 2010.10 I installed VMware. Then I installed the 2011.04beta1 in VMware. Evrything worked fine, but after updating packages and rebooting I got the following popup:

> It seems that you do not have the
>   hardware required to run Unity. Please
>   choose Ubuntu Classic at the login
>   screen and you will be using the
>   traditional environment.

It opens a session anyway. I have never tried Unity but I am pretty sure it opened a plain old Gnome session.

How can I trick out VMware to support Unity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dont think the vmware guest tools support Unity 3d yet - I havent had any luck with VMWare Player 3.x.  See this also - [How do I know if my video card can run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34579/how-do-i-know-if-my-video-card-can-run-unity)

You could try installing unity-2d, or try using Virtualbox which does work with Unity 3d (most of the time).

See this link for install instructions - http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/how-to-test-ubuntu-1104-with-unity-in.html

Answer (score 0):

If using VirtualBox, you need to enable 3D acceleration in the VM settings (Display->Enable 3D acceleration).

Answer (score 0):

If using VirtualBox, also don't forget set up [Guest Addition](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html).