# Asus eee PC R011PX (Unity) 3D support ?

Tags: unity, drivers, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I know if my video card can run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34579/how-do-i-know-if-my-video-card-can-run-unity)

I want to know if there is any chance to get Unity 3d working wit my Netbook?. I tried the x-swat (Ubuntu-X) ppa but when i log in to the workspace the sidebar ant the bar on the top are not visible. The netbook has a Intel GMA 3150 integrated graphic chip and a Intel Atom 570 as cpu. Hope somebody can help me.

Cya