# What are the requirements to have unity 3D running/available

Tags: unity, system-requirements

What are the **hardware requirements** to have so that Unity 3D will be available and work when starting Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I know if my video card can run Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34579/how-do-i-know-if-my-video-card-can-run-unity)

Comment: Actually not looking for "How to know if the video card works with unity" but the actual requirements for Unity 3D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to running `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` you should have a read through the Ubuntu Wiki Documentation on the following two pages;

[Unity Hardware Requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements)

[Demystifying Unity's Graphics Hardware Requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DemystifyingUnityGraphicsHardwareRequirements)

Comment: I like the second link. The first one is very informative. The second one kills all doubt.

Answer (score 2):

General recommended system requirements for Ubuntu can be found at [this Ubuntu Documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements). In addition to those, you should also see [How do I know if my video card can run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34579/18612) to check whether your video card is good enough to run Unity 3D.