# Speed up Ubuntu or to walk away?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, turbo-boost

I did install Ubuntu 14 32 bits in a Pentium 4 3GHz HT with 3GB RAM (max possible). First I used an IDE HD, but since it was too slow, I'd put a SATA HD and the speed increased a little bit. But Ubuntu runs really slowly, barely usable. It was disappointing because I did install this version (14) because I think 16 was too much for this hardware, but I'm not sure if worth to install an even older version (12, 11...). So what I am asking might be subjective a little bit, but I need to hear some specialist opinion on this.

My guess is what is making the system slow is the interface (mostly), not the processes. I think is more about the appearance and less about the system itself. I have a simple graphic card: nVidia GF Fx5200 128MB, maybe not enough to run the heavy Ubuntu graphic interface.

So if it is possible to speed up Ubuntu, maybe is a better idea to install version 16 (the latest one) and boost it - what you think?

I'm aware there is other "variations" of Ubuntu like Lubuntu, Xubuntu... is there some made for cases like mine? Can I be up to date and be happy?

Or should I just walk away from Ubuntu and look for another OS to run decently this hardware?

Comment: It's worth trying Lubuntu.  My old netbook could not run Ubuntu's Unity 3d desktop without slowing to a crawl. It works well on Lubuntu.  Your PC is better than my netbook.

Comment: You can check how good your graphics card can handle unity with `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p `. Reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34579/how-do-i-know-if-my-video-card-can-run-unity

Comment: Looking at graphics requirements in Ubuntu Wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements it seams to me my graphic card is not qualified (I did comparisons in videocardbenchmark). It's amazing that still works, with some psychedelic video effects in the boot. So I'll take look at Lubuntu and Xubuntu, following the advices. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try a different Ubuntu flavor**

Ubuntu, which runs on the Unity desktop environment, has a lot of "eye-candy" and slows down the system. Use a lighter, faster Ubuntu flavor.

**Which one?**

Lubuntu, or even Xubuntu, is super light. Use it instead of normal Ubuntu.

**Use the newest version**

The newer, the better. Every Ubuntu version comes with improvments with a newer kernel therefore 16.04 is better.

Comment: Your answer was almost ok, but you should include Xubuntu as suggested by TenPlus1 because Lubuntu seams to be for real week hardware as old notebooks. I'm not trying to install Xubuntu, it runs ok in the DVD, seams to be the best choice for my PC.

Comment: OK will add it @user6492

Answer (score 1):

Xubuntu 16.04 is a lightweight XFCE desktop instead of Unity and will run quicker using less memory: https://xubuntu.org/news/xubuntu-16-04-release/